# Android surface flickering between buffers

Tags: android, linux, configuration, framebuffer, surfaceflinger

I am having a problem with my Android system. It is running on a custom platform and when I boot up the device the screen flickers between the `bootanim` and the console "`A N D R O I D` " screen.

When the `bootanim` redraws itself it is visible but then it quickly flickers back to the "`A N D R O I D` " screen.

I suspect that this is due to some setting of SurfaceFlinger or OpenGL however I can't find much documentation on then - except the source.

Do I need to define something in my device configs specific for my platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix this issue.

It is related to the kernel config. To stop the 'flickering' I needed to unset CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE.

My `bootanim` now displays beautifully...!